# Save file settings in ini instead of registry

Tags: mfc

I'm new to MFC, once I create my first app, in myApp::InitInstance() . I have

```
SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));
```

Can I delete this and save settings to my own ini construct ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** After further testing, the solution below does not work if your app class is derived from `CWinAppEx` ! It does work if your app is directly derived from `CWinApp`.

---

To store values in an `.ini` file instead of the registry:

1. Omit the call to `SetRegistryKey`.
2. In your app class, set `m_pszProfileName` to the full path of your `.ini` file. The filename string **must** be allocated using `malloc`, because the framework will call `free` on it when your app shuts down. First `free` the existing value, then assign your new string:

   `free((void*)m_pszProfileName);

   m_pszProfileName = ::_tcsdup(_T("C:\\somedir\\myini.ini"));`
3. Call `CWinApp::GetProfileInt`, `CWinApp::WriteProfileInt` and similar functions as usual.

I strongly recommend using a path under APPDATA for storing your `.ini` file.

Comment: I discovered that this solution doesn’t work if your app class is a subclass of `CWinAppEx`. It still works if your app is a direct subclass of `CWinApp`. I tested it with a dialog-based app, which is based on `CWinApp`, which is why I didn’t catch the error.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. CWinApp::SetProfileXXX() does this for you, actually - but I wouldn't use these methods anymore in 2010, they were OK when ppl moved from .ini to the registry.

Comment: I see people really love ini file the program will be portable, registry is messy sometimes . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is possible as a .ini file has only strings for your program. You can create an operating system script (.bat for windows, .sh for unix etc) and call it using system() call.

Answer (score 1):

Use win32 APIs **WriteProfileString** (write to INI file) and **GetProfileString** (read from INI file)
For more help 
ms-help://MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/sysinfo/base/writeprofilestring.htm

Comment: These functions are deprecated and retained for win16 compatibility. You should not be using them or recommending them.