# How to disable MFC writing workspace settings to registry?

Tags: c++, mfc, registry

By default, a basic MFC C++ project in Visual Studio 2010 will store all its workspace settings in the HKCU registry hive under a user-configurable key name.  This includes last window size/position, ribbon settings, status bar, etc.

How can you disable this feature completely so as to not write to the registry at all?

I tried not setting `SetRegistryKey()`, which gave me a debug assertion from the framework on first read/write to registry.  `SetRegistryKey((LPCTSTR)NULL)` gave the same results.  `SetRegistryBase()` seems to have no effect.  No other methods in `CWinApp`/`CWinAppEx` seem to help.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** My original answer was wrong. I have edited the answer.

---

<strike>You can tell MFC to store settings in an `.ini` file instead of the registry. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995679/save-file-settings-in-ini-instead-of-registry/4000236#4000236).</strike> (Update: That only works if you are not using `CWinAppEx`.)

If you want to prevent MFC from saving *some of* the state of the menus and toolbars <strike>altogether</strike>, add the following to your app’s constructor:

```
m_bSaveState = FALSE;
```

The `m_bSaveState` member is only defined if your app is derived from `CWinAppEx`.

Alternatively, you can override `CWinAppEx::SaveState` and `CWinAppEx::LoadState`.

---

To eliminate the `WindowPlacement` registry key, override `CWinAppEx::StoreWindowPlacement`.

You may still get other registry entries being written. A complete solution would involve subclassing `CSettingsStore` and then, in your application, calling `CSettingsStoreSP::SetRuntimeClass`. ([See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309001.aspx) for more information.) This is fairly difficult because there are a whole bunch of virtual functions you will have to override in your custom `CSettingsStore` class.

Comment: This partially worked.  Setting to `FALSE` disabled a number of reg keys, but a couple still remained.  Overriding `SaveState()`/`LoadState()` to do nothing reduced it down to just "WindowPosition" being saved.  The answer in the referenced question didn't work.  Got an assertion from omitting call to `SetRegistryKey()` and even if not, the .ini file was not created.  Might be a VS2010 difference?

Comment: Yikes. I was testing with a `CWinApp`-derived class, not `CWinAppEx`. Thanks for the heads-up. I updated the answer to show how you can get rid of `WindowPlacement`. (Is that what you meant when you said “WindowPosition”?)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late for many but I found that CFrameWndEx -- it will be in your CMainFrame class -- uses WM_CLOSE window to SAVE your applications default location. I do not know what loads the location. However, if you override WM_CLOSE, then that window state is never saved when you exit the program. It will attempt to re-load your last window state, but since none was ever save to begin with, there's nothing to worry about.

A GOTCHA SITUATION:
Since the framework DOES still call some sort of WM_INIT function to LOAD the last position, if you compiled your code as normal, maximize the application window, closed the program with the X, WM_CLOSE would have saved the application state as MAXIMIZED. If you recompile the app by overriding WM_CLOSE as mentioned above, re-launch the application, you'll notice it starts out maximized! Obvious not what you intended. Thus, you must re-activate (comment out WM_CLOSE), let the program save the application state by re-launch the program, when closing as a normal window.  Allow the overridden WM_CLOSE to work again and you'll see that normal window reappears.

CODE:

**In your CMainFrame.h**

*public:
    afx_msg void OnClose();*

**In your CMainFrame.cpp ... Extend your MESSAGE MAP**

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWndEx)



*ON_WM_CLOSE() // <<< I ADDED THIS*
```

....
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()

**void CMainFrame::OnClose()**
{

```
PostQuitMessage(0);
//CFrameWndEx::OnClose(); << WE DO NOT WANT TO HAVE THIS CALLED!
```

}